# Problems with link aggregation with Mate 16.04

Tags: networking, network-bridge, network-bonding

Following a motherboard failure, I have upgraded my system and rebuilt the system disk with Mate 16.04 (which I was running before. I have put in a dual NIC, disabled the onboard NIC in bios and have spent the last 6 hours trying unsuccessfully to bond the 2 NICs. I have set up the switch (Netgear GS108T) for IEEE 802.3ad LACP bonding. I have tried various variations on the following: (Bonding mode is loaded in etc/modules and ifenslave is installed and up to date)

```
sudo service NetworkManager stop
sudo modprobe bonding
sudo pluma /etc/network/interfaces
```

I inputed the following

```
# eth0 is manually configured, and slave to the "bond0" bonded NIC
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0

# eth1 ditto, thus creating a 2-link bond.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

# bond0 is the bonding NIC and can be used like any other normal NIC.
# bond0 is configured using static network information.
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    gateway x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves none
```

I then restarted the service and ran`sudo ifup bond0`this resulted in time out and it could not bond the either of the nics.
When I ran 
`more /proc/net/bonding/bond0` I got the output

```
Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
```

Having spent hours on this and other slight variations, I tried a different tack and tried something else I'd seen

```
   auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
network x.x.x.x
gateway 0.0.0.0
bond-slaves none
bond-mode 0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond0
```

This still did not work, when I tried to bring up the bond (could not bond either nic), but at least this time I got an output that was different, albeit limited (it showed the bonding mode as LACP; I don't have the full output).

I've given up now, but I would like to get this sorted. Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where I was going wrong

```
sudo ifup bond0
```

did not activate the bond properly. Restarting the pc did this and it all worked a treat.

It was a proper DOH moment, I can tell you!!! I'm just not used to restarting a linux box these days, anyone would think I was still on Windows :-D